# How to switch keyboard keys in my laptop

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

My laptop's keyboard is not functioning properly recently

especially the key "W" and i get frustrated trying to push this key several times in order to get a "W" and this slows me back significantly

I was thinking if I can switch this key ith another key such as "~" as i hardly use this key.

Any one have tried this before? how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a program like sharpkeys to switch keys:

[image]